# How do I insert a description in a Facebook share-link without using a meta-tag?

Tags: facebook

How do I create a custom description and image when im creating a share-link on my site? I know I can set title, url and an image with metatags, but that doesn't solve what i'm trying to do.

[Facebook Share/Specifying Meta Tags](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Share/Specifying_Meta_Tags)

What I have seen other places and want to do is include a specific description and picture to the shared link. Like a quiz the user takes, and the result is posted along with the link, and a picture that changes along with the users score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a static page with that content, since the "share" action is Facebook hitting your page (not the user's browser).

Look at how the 'like' websites do it.

http://www.fblike.net/

They save the content in a DB, and make a unique page for each user submitted content.

Comment: Yes, that would work. I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve any backend programming.